# Why is this simple PHP login script not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

I am very new to PHP and JavaScript and I have made a PHP and Javascript login script. However, it just shoots out **Incorrect username or password.** even though it's correct. Here are my scripts:

PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    if($username == "axqua" && $password == "abc")
    {
        $loggedin = true;
        echo "Logged in as axqua";
    }
    else
    {
        $loggedin = false;
        echo "Incorrect username or password.";
    }
?>
```

Javascript:

```
        <script>
            var username = document.getElementById("usernameform").value.toString();
            var password = document.getElementById("passwordform").value.toString();

            var formData = {'username':username, 'password':password}

            function posttourl() {
                var posts = $.ajax({
                    'url': 'http://example.com/',
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'data': formData
                })

                posts.done(function (res) {
                    console.log(res)
                })
            }
        </script>
```

HTML:

```
        <p class="text">Username</p>
        <input class="inputstyle" maxlength="12" id="usernameform">
        <br>
        <p class="text">Password</p>
        <input class="inputstyle" type="password" maxlength="16" id="passwordform">
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="button" onclick="posttourl()">Login</a>
```

I do not see a problem with this so I am not sure what is going on but if you can help then please do.

Comment: Try removing the two .tostring() from your script

Comment: Hm, it seems that you read the username and password before the user entered the text. Try moving the three lines of vars into inside posttourl()

Comment: @KenLee Did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Martheen THANK YOU! This worked and I can now carry on with my code. If you want you can respond to this answer and I'll mark it as correct so maybe other people with the same problem can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by the comment, this is because the JS section run before the user entered the text (likely on page load), so

```
var username = document.getElementById("usernameform").value.toString();
var password = document.getElementById("passwordform").value.toString();
var formData = {'username':username, 'password':password}
```

are executed when the text boxes are empty, ignoring later input. Moving them into `posttourl()` ensure the values taken are current.